# String Not Displaying In Edit Text

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I have created an intent which gets the values entered into two Edit Texts and sends them as an intent to another class when a submit button is clicked, here is the code:

```
Button bSubmit1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit2); //Submit Button
    bSubmit1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String entry_Minutes = entryminutes.getText().toString();
            String entry_Hours = entryhours.getText().toString();

            Intent i=new Intent("com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.MOVINGSTRINGS");
            i.putExtra("Entry_Minutes", entry_Minutes);
            i.putExtra("Entry_Hours", entry_Hours);
            startActivity(i);
```

the activity in the next class is then started where the strings sent in the intent are supposed to be then displayed in another two edit text's, however nothing is appearing in the two edit text boxes. Here is the other part of the code in the other class:

```
public class EntryStatistics extends Activity {

EditText hoursBox, minutesBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entrystatistics);

    hoursBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry_hours);
    minutesBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry_minutes);

    String entry_minutes = getIntent().getStringExtra("Entry_Minutes");
    if(entry_minutes!=null){
        return;
    }
    String entry_hours = getIntent().getStringExtra("Entry_Hours");
    if(entry_hours!=null){
        return;
    }


    hoursBox.setText(entry_hours);
    minutesBox.setText(entry_minutes);
```

Can anyone be able to tell me why the values in the strings aren't being displayed in the edit texts? Nothing is displayed at all. Thanks

Here is the full error messages:

```
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper/com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.EntryStatistics}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.EntryStatistics.onCreate(EntryStatistics.java:34)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  ... 11 more
```

Here is line 34 and 35:

```
hoursBox.setText(entry_hours);
minutesBox.setText(entry_minutes);
```

Comment: place your complete error log

Comment: what does 34th line of entrystatics.java contains or place your entrystatics.java full code

Answer (score 1):

IT looks like a simple typo in your null checks.  You're currently ignoring the strings if they aren't null, when it should be the other way around.

The fix should be relatively simple. Just change

```
if(entry_minutes!=null){
    return;
}
```

to

```
if(entry_minutes==null){
    return;
}
```

Once you've done this for both strings, the `EditText`s should update without problems.

Comment: Hello, I have made the changes however when I click the submit button on the first class it now displays an error and closes the application. The error says:   04-14 02:10:08.888: E/AndroidRuntime(332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper/com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.EntryStatistics}: java.lang.NullPointerException             Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your EditTexts aren't null, and that the views are being found correctly?

Comment: The values that are being stored are integer e.g. 4 if that helps?

Comment: Probably not. Step through the code in a debugger, and make sure that the calls to `findViewById()` don't return null.

Answer (score 0):

uses this trick :

---

### ClassX:

```
static String entry_Minutes="",entry_Hours="";
Button bSubmit1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit2); //Submit Button
    bSubmit1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            entry_Minutes = entryminutes.getText().toString();
            entry_Hours = entryhours.getText().toString();

            Intent i=new Intent("com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.MOVINGSTRINGS");
            startActivity(i);
```

---

### EntryStatistics:

```
public class EntryStatistics extends Activity {

EditText hoursBox, minutesBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entrystatistics);

    hoursBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry_hours);
    minutesBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry_minutes);

    hoursBox.setText(ClassX.entry_Hours);
    minutesBox.setText(ClassX.entry_Minutes);
```

Comment: This is not what he is looking for. This is an alternative way of sharing the data.

Comment: If we properly implemented, there will be no problems.

Comment: and also making more static variables is not a good idea as it will increase the scope of the variables and needs more memory.

Answer (score 0):

This can be clearly observed step by step by running the application in Debugging mode by keeping some debugging points and using F6 for step by step execution.

---

Sending or Receiving Objects or Strings

**Sending string data**

As we already know that we can transfer from one to other Activity by using Intents.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GoActivity.class);

String data = “bla bla”;// Data String to send

i.putExtra("DATA",data );
```

**Receiving the Data**

We can receive the above the string data as shown below.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String data = i.getStringExtra("DATA");// you well get the String data i.e., BLA BLA
```

The Red Colored DATA should be same while sending and receiving the data.

**Sending Object**

Here is the code to send the Object from one to other class. One Important thing to send the Object is the class should implement the Serializable class.

The below Red Colored text should be same.

//MainActivity.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,startActivity.class);

ObjectClassName object = new ObjectClassName();

i.putExtra("THIS", Object);
```

**Receiving Object**

// startActivity.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ObjectClassName obj = (ObjectClassName) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("THIS");// TypeCasting needed
```

Comment: Hello, I am not entirely sure in what you want me to do, I have started the application in debugging mode however I am not sure on the steps after that

Comment: Click on the image http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-4.gif . Here you can see a small drop at the left side of the line. which denotes that the code is pointed for debugging. Where ever in the code, you want to check the variables usage, flow and their values, keep debug points over there. Again try to start application in debug mode.

Comment: After opening the debug mode, F8 will move directlt to the next debug point and while f6 moves step by step. so that you can know the complete step by step flow.

Comment: For more information about sending and receiving objects or strings, updated my answer

Comment: For more info on how to debug you app check the http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html. Check the last method  of debugging. It helps you in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String entry_minutes = getIntent().getStringExtra("Entry_Minutes");
    if(entry_minutes==null){
        return;
    }
    String entry_hours = getIntent().getStringExtra("Entry_Hours");
    if(entry_hours==null){
        return;
    }
```

because the current lines returns you because entry_minutes is not null and as per your condition its true. change it to equals to.
Also from your first activity you are calling a new activity like below

```
Intent i=new Intent("com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.MOVINGSTRINGS");
```

you have the code for EntryStatistics activity and i dont think you have called EntryStatistics activity.

just change the above intent to below and try::

```
Intent i=new Intent(ThisActivityName.this,EntryStatistics.class);
```

Comment: Hello, I changed it to the code you put above (==) however when I click the submit button on the first class it now displays an error and closes the application. The error says: 04-14 02:10:08.888: E/AndroidRuntime(332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper/com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.‌​EntryStatistics}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Hello, I changed the intent code to the one you suggested above, however the error still persists. Thanks

Comment: check whether String entry_Minutes, String entry_Hours, in your first activity are null?

Comment: 04-14 03:00:47.300: E/AndroidRuntime(373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper/com.lukeorpin.theappliancekeeper.EntryStatistics}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: In the first activity they are the values of the inputs the user puts into the two edit texts:                            entry_Minutes = entryminutes.getText().toString();
entry_Hours = entryhours.getText().toString();